# Bash menu that shows the command on the prompt (without the command executing)

Tags: bash

I want to write a simple menu script in bash.
This is what I have now:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "************ MENU ************"
echo "  1)Show dir"
echo "  2)Current Dir"

read n
case $n in
  1) ls ;;
  2) pwd ;;
  *) echo "invalid option";;
esac
```

This script works, when I press 1 it executes the ls command.
But what I want is this:

when I press 1 I want the ls command on the prompt without executing it so I can add a folder name myself and then press enter.

or is possible to add some kind of user parameter here like, when I press 1, I type a folder name and the script executes ls with my folder name?

in the end I want to achieve a menu for exiftool:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "************ MENU ************"
echo "  1)Basic rename"
echo "  2)Exif info"


read n
case $n in
  1) exiftool -d "%Y-%m-%d %H,%M,%S%%-c" '-filename<${DateTimeOriginal} $Make-$Model.%e' ;;
  2) exiftool  ;;
  *) echo "invalid option";;
esac
```

So when I press 1, I want to paste this exiftool command without pressing enter so I can drag some photo's from finder to my terminal and after that I press enter to rename.

Oh I work on a mac, not sure if that maters.

Comment: You can try `read -ei "ls " && $REPLY`... but injecting user input in a command is a security issue (and hence considered very bad practice). What's your program supposed to do?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I adjusted my post about the reason why I make this script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're strategy is the good one, and here's a suggestion: instead, use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

exiftool -d "%Y-%m-%d %H,%M,%S%%-c" '-filename<${DateTimeOriginal} $Make-$Model.%e' "$@"
```

Call it whatever you like (I'm going to call it `banana`) and use it like so:

```
$ ./banana [and here paste/drop the files to process]
```

I think this will be a lot cleaner than what you're trying to do.

Maybe you'll want to have more than one `exif` command with different parameters. That's not a problem: we can help you solve that if needed.

This will be superior to the obsolete “menu choice” design in that you can use this script within other scripts or automated processes. (But you can't easily with the menu design).

Comment: You are right, if it's just one exiftool command, then I won't bother writing a menu script for that :-) but I have a few commands, 1 basic rename, 2 show geotag in Google maps, 3 move photo's to subfolder like yyyy\mm etc, etc

Comment: Interesting consideration, thank you. But this is not what the PO is asking for.

Comment: @RalphSchipper That's why I suspected... in this case you can either: (1) have one script per task, or (2) have your script parse the arguments to determine what task to perform: it would then be used as `./banana rename ...` or `./banana geotag ...`. That would be a great design (and you could also have arguments within these commands). It's very simple to implement, let me know if you need help with that.

Comment: @PierreFrançois yes, it seems there's a mismatch between what OP asks and what OP wants, but it's easy to understand what he wants!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: brllliant answer, chapeau: ce qui se conçoit bien s'énonce clairement, et les mots pour le dire arrivent aisément. Anyway, people searching in the future for answers in SO and looking for the answer to the question "Bash menu that executes a command without enter" will be interested in the optional arguments of the `read` command.

Comment: @PierreFrançois ah un voisin Belge ! amitié de France, en espérant que ce moment n'est pas trop douloureux pour vous et vos proches ! The title should probably be edited to reflect the actual issue... oh well, let's see how the question evolves. Cheers!

Comment: ahhhhh now I get it, you can interpret the subject in 2 ways, pressing enter in the menu of pressing enter at the command line.. I changed the topic subject :-)

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Thanks I think I can work with that, I gonna try to implement the ./banan rename ./banana geotag etc. thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you issue `read -n 1`, the pressed key is passed immediately to the script, without waiting for <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Adding the `-s` option prevents the character just being read to be echoed.

So try:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "************ MENU ************"
echo "  1) Show dir"
echo "  2) Current Dir"

read -n 1 -s n
case $n in
  1) ls ;;
  2) pwd ;;
  *) echo "invalid option";;
esac
```

It works like a charm.

Comment: Ok, if I do that then it just executes ls and it shows me files, what I want is: press 1 and I want to see ls on the prompt so I can drag a folder to the terminal and then I press enter